# How can I combine two queries opencmis alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis

I want to get all files that have either aspect A or aspect B.

Here are my queries:

```
SELECT * FROM <ASPECT A>

SELECT * FROM <ASPECT B>`
```

I know that UNION doesn't exist in opencmis, so is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do it in CMIS.

But you can post process result in your webscript by simply joining them. Since you marked your question with `java` tag I suppose you are using Java backed webscript in which result of CMIS query is stored in `ItemIterable<QueryResult>` collection. So just execute both queries and merge result in one collection.